# pygame image scale failed

Tags: python, pygame, scale

I am about to resize a image. Here is the code:

```
def display_image(self):
    print('the original size of the image is: ' + str(self.image.get_rect().size))
    self.resize_image(self.image)
    print('the size after resizing is: ' + str(self.image.get_rect().size))
    #some other code in the function

def resize_image(self, image):
    ratio_w = image.get_width()/self.width  #self.width is the width of the screen
    ratio_h = image.get_height()/self.height  #self.height is the height of the screen
    ration = max(ratio_w, ratio_h)
    new_w = image.get_width()/ratio
    new_h = image.get_height()/ration
    image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(new_w),int(new_h)))
```

According to the print result, the size of the image is not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `resize_image`,

```
image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(new_w),int(new_h)))
```

is reassigning the parameter to the function. It's not changing `self.image`.

You could return the new image and assign it back to `self.image`.

```
def resize_image(self, image):
    #....
    return pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(new_w),int(new_h)))
```

And

```
def display_image(self):
    print('the original size of the image is: ' + str(self.image.get_rect().size))
    self.image = self.resize_image(self.image)
    print('the size after resizing is: ' + str(self.image.get_rect().size))
    #some other code in the function
```